# check if property value exist before push item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Below is my sample code that pushes into VacanciesWithSavedSearches array by checking if the item does not already exist.

```
 if ($scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.indexOf(value) == -1) {

            $scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.push({
                type: "Saved Searches",
                title: value.title,
                value: value.id
            });
        }
```

How do I change the above by replacing indexOf with the actually property value, e.g Add item to the list VacanciesWithSavedSearches if the list do not contain another item.id=123

Comment: Are you sure you need an Array for `VacanciesWithSavedSearches`? If you're looking up by unique ID, then an object or map would seem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array.filter

```
var result = $scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.filter(t=t.id ==='123');
if(result.length === 0)
{
  $scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.push({
     type: "Saved Searches",
     title: value.title,
     value: value.id
   });          

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.some:

If Ecmascript6 is not a problem:

```
var id = 123;
if (!$scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.some(vac => vac.id === id)) {
    $scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.push({
         type: "Saved Searches",
         title: value.title,
         value: id
     });
 }
```

With Ecmascript5, you can do it like below:

```
var id = 123;
if (!$scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.some(function(vac) { return vac.id === id; })) {
    $scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.push({
         type: "Saved Searches",
         title: value.title,
         value: id
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array was an array of numbers or primitives you could do `.indexOf(value) == -1`  but it's an array of objects so you can't test it with `.indexOf()` method, you can use **[`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method to test over the existence of your object in the array.

> The `some()` method tests whether at-least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

This is how should be your code:

```
if (!$scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.some(function(v){return v.value.id === -1})) {
     $scope.VacanciesWithSavedSearches.push({
          type: "Saved Searches",
          title: value.title,
          value: value.id
     });
}
```